# access private field in recipientflow expression

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el

A quick question on SPEL syntax in Spring Integration.

In the following code sample, what's the correct way to access `myMember`within a SPEL expression?

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor //Lombok
public class MyClass(

    // autowired member
    private final MyMember myMember;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(...)
            .routeToRecipients(
                r -> r.ignoreSendFailures(false)
                      .recipientFlow(...)
                      // #this and #root both refer to the message and give access
                      // to payload and headers, but can I also access myMember
                      // in this SPEL expression?
                      .recipientFlow("@#?...myMember.method(...)", // returns true or false
                                     subflow())
            ) 
            ...
            .get();
}
```

I can of course easily work this around by setting a header with the results of myMember.method(...) beforehand, but I was wondering if I could use a shortcut.

Comment: Nevermind, I just re-read the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-routers) and saw there is a version of `recipientFlow`  that accepts a `FunctionExpression`.

Comment: You can add this as an answer with a comprehensive sample to help other seekers to get an answer immediately. And of course you can accept it yourself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-routers) gives a few examples of recipient methods to use in the `RecipientListRouterSpec` parameter of the `routeToRecipients` method:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow recipientListFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("recipientListInput")
            .<String, String>transform(p -> p.replaceFirst("Payload", ""))
            .routeToRecipients(r -> r
                    .recipient("thing1-channel", "'thing1' == payload")
                    .recipientMessageSelector("thing2-channel", m ->
                            m.getHeaders().containsKey("recipient")
                                    && (boolean) m.getHeaders().get("recipient"))
                    .recipientFlow("'thing1' == payload or 'thing2' == payload or 'thing3' == payload",
                            f -> f.<String, String>transform(String::toUpperCase)
                                    .channel(c -> c.queue("recipientListSubFlow1Result")))
                    .recipientFlow((String p) -> p.startsWith("thing3"),
                            f -> f.transform("Hello "::concat)
                                    .channel(c -> c.queue("recipientListSubFlow2Result")))
                    .recipientFlow(new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>(m ->
                                    "thing3".equals(m.getPayload())),
                            f -> f.channel(c -> c.queue("recipientListSubFlow3Result")))
                    .defaultOutputToParentFlow())
            .get();
}
```

The last example of the `recipientFlow` methods above is the one that takes an [Expression](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/expression/Expression.html) and an [IntegrationFlow](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/dsl/IntegrationFlow.html) as parameters. This integration flow is invoked only if the expression evaluates to `true`.

A [FunctionExpression](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/expression/FunctionExpression.html) can be used to solve the OP:

```
    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor //Lombok
    public class MyClass(
    
        // autowired member
        private final MyMember myMember;
    
        @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
            return IntegrationFlows
                .from(...)
                .routeToRecipients(
                    r -> r.ignoreSendFailures(false)
                          .recipientFlow(...)
                          .recipientFlow(new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>(
                              m -> myMember.method(...), // returns true or false
                              subflow())
                ) 
                ...
                .get();
    }
```